# How to evaluate code in ace editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get html code from ace editor and show preview in `iframe`.

Example: [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-9x6JW/0/2?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b)

Here is what i have been trying:

```
var textarea = $('textarea[name="html"]');
var view=$('#view');
textarea.hide();
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    var preview = view.eval(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
setTimeout(preview, 300);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var textarea = $('textarea[name="html"]');
var view=$('#view');
textarea.hide();
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    view.contents().find('body').html(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
```

I presumed `view` is your `iframe`.

I am using the `contents()` jQuery function to get into the `iframe` and replace the html with what is in the editor.